# How to use ampersands and asterisks when passing pointers by reference into functions

Tags: c++

From EPI 19.4, the question asks to find any cycles in a directed graph. The strategy is to label nodes by the colors white, grey and black during DFS such that when two grey nodes are iterated in succession, a cycle is found.

My issue here is not with understanding the strategy, it is with the implementation in which asterisks and ampersands are used to reference pointers and pass pointers by reference into functions.

```
struct GraphVertex {
    enum Color { white, gray, black } color = white;
    vector<GraphVertex*> edges; // Line A
};

bool IsDeadlocked(vector<GraphVertex>* G) { // Line B
    return any_of(begin(*G), end(*G), [](GraphVertex& vertex) { // Line C
        return vertex.color == GraphVertex::white && HasCycle(&vertex); // Line D
    });
}

bool HasCycle(GraphVertex* cur) { // Line E
    if (cur->color == GraphVertex::gray) {
        return true;
    }

    cur->color = GraphVertex::gray;
    for (GraphVertex*& next : cur->edges) { // Line F
        if (next->color != GraphVertex::black) {
            if (HasCycle(next)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    cur->color = GraphVertex::black;
    return false;
}
```

In line A, common usage, no issues.

In line B, graph representation is `vector<GraphVertex>`, why is it not `vector<GraphVertex*>`? Upon re-reading, it seems all the confusion below would be negated by using `vector<GraphVertex*>`.

In line C, `begin()`/`end()` returns iterators to `GraphVertex` structs. So shouldn't the iterators be dereferenced to access the `GraphVertex` struct itself? The lambda function argument is of type `GraphVertex&`, is this passing the `GraphVertex` type by reference? But `begin()`/`end()` returned iterators so wouldn't it make more sense for the lambda function argument to be of type `GraphVertex*`?

In line D, `&vertex` implies that the input parameter of type `GraphVertex&` is actually not a pointer to `GraphVertex` but is the `GraphVertex` struct itself, and only now is the address being referenced to pass as a pointer into the `HasCycle` function, which does require a pointer. Then by deduction, `GraphVertex&` in line C must be the method used to dereference the iterator to obtain a variable of type `GraphVertex`. Is this correct? But isn't derefencing done by `GraphVertex*`?

In line E, the function parameter is a pointer to `GraphVertex`, as seen earlier.

In line F, the iterator is of type `GraphVertex*&`, which is a reference to a pointer. The ampersand here ensures that when the elements of `GraphVertex*` are accessed, it is the actual elements and not a copy.

The language used here to describe the technicalities is unfortunately basic and reveals a lack of understanding on the whole.

Comment: `&` in an argument list means "reference", but in a function call it means "address of".

Comment: This code seems to be a consequence of how sometimes references pop up unexpectedly, such as when using `for (auto x : y)`, or as a necessity, such as when trying to mutate an argument. There's nothing really weird going on here so long as you understand what references are, how they're declared, and what they imply.

Comment: Shouldn't B be `vector<GraphVertex*> G` to match the type in the `struct`? This is where a small `typedef` to keep things consistent can help.

Comment: @tadman It definitely shouldn't. Something has to own the vertices, and it makes sense for the graph to own its vertices. It doesn't make sense for an edge to own its vertices. So the graph itself should consist of a vector of the vertices themselves, not pointers to them. While edges should have pointers to the vertices they connect, since they don't own them.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It's hard to tell without other code for context. It could be `vector<GraphVertex>&` instead then, as would make more sense. If that's possible, then the `hasCycle` function can also take a reference.

Comment: @tadman Sure, you could change the code that way. But it's quite easy to tell that the graph owns its vertices and the edges have pointers to them. That's a quite common pattern and clearly used given the design of the struct and the `IsDeadlocked` function. No need to add additional confusion.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I like Kostas' advice down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your confusion is centered around lines B and C, so let's break it down.

Line B uses the parameter `vector<GraphVertex>* G`. This means that this vector *owns* all of these GraphVertices - it contains the actual vertex data and is in charge of allocating and deallocating them. The fact that this is passed by pointer is just to avoid copying the vector when the function is called.

Ok, so what does that mean for Line A? The vertices don't own other vertices - so they store them by pointer. These are pointing at GraphVertices which are in the vector on line B.

For line C, `begin()` and `end()` return iterators, and you are correct that they do have to be dereferenced to get a reference to the actual GraphVertex struct. This dereference happens for you inside of the `any_of` call, which is why the lambda takes a reference.

So in line D, `vertex` is a reference to a `GraphVertex` inside of `G`. `&vertex` just converts that reference into a pointer, nothing special.

And on line F, the `&` is completely redundant in this case. This probably is from common practice of writing `for (Foo& foo : fooList)` - but here it is just confusing.

Finally other answers have good suggestions as far as style.

Answer (score 1):

There are certain conventions to be followed in C++.

**Line A**: `T*` or `std::reference_wrapper<T>` are both acceptable ways of storing object in an `std::vector`, when it does not own the elements. Otherwise `T` or `std::unique/shared_ptr<T>` should be used.

**Line B, C, D, E**: When passing read-only objects in a function it should be done by const reference `const T&`. If object is to be mutated then `T&`. Pass by raw pointer should very rarely be used.

**Line F**: The reference is redundant here. A pointer by definition points to the original data and makes no copies. a `T*&` would make sense if you were planning to change where the pointer points (e.g. make it point to a new object).

A lot of these conventions are not used here, which creates confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> In line B, graph representation is vector, why is it not vector<GraphVertex*>? Upon re-reading, it seems all the confusion below would be negated by using vector<GraphVertex*>.

Then who or what would own the vertices? It makes logical sense for the graph to own its vertices. If it has pointers to them -- where are they going to be exactly?

Since the vertices can only be in one place, and in this case it makes sense to keep them in the `vector` that represents the graph itself, then edges will need pointers (or references) to them.